# How to create a function-like macro token by pasting tokens together

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I have a set of predefined macros (That I cannot change) where each one takes as input the index for an array. I want to create another macro to be able to choose which previously defined macro to use by pasting the tokens together.

I have tried creating a macro that takes in 2 arguments: `x`, which picks which previously defined macro to use, and `ind`, which is passed on to the selected macro.

The code below is ran using 
https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler
so I can figure out the basic code before I put it into a rather large application.

```
#include <stdio.h>

//struct creation
struct mystruct {
    int x;
    int y;
};

//create array of structs
struct mystruct sArr1[2] = {{1,2},{3,4}};
struct mystruct sArr2[2] = {{5,6},{7,8}};

//define macros
#define MAC1(ind) (sArr1[ind].x)
#define MAC2(ind) (sArr2[ind].y)

// Cannot change anything above this //

//my attempt at 2 input macro
#define MYARR(x,ind) MAC ## x ## (ind)

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", MYARR(1, 0));
    return 0;
}
```

I want the result to print out the `x` value of `sArr1` at index `0`, which is `1`. Instead, I get this output

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:29:22: error: pasting "MAC1" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
 #define MYARR(x,ind) MAC ## x ## (ind)
                      ^
main.c:33:19: note: in expansion of macro ‘MYARR’
     printf("%d\n", MYARR(1, 0));
```

Comment: First of all, token-pasting creates a *single* token. And if you read the error message closely you will see that it pasted `MAC` and `1` together correctly, and the problem is pasting `MAC1` with the `(` (of `(ind)`). Should you really have a *single token*  (i.e. a single preprocessor symbol) `MAC1(`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

line 29 should be :

```
#define MYARR(x,ind) MAC##x(ind)
```

I tested it. It printed '1', which is what you want.

Comment: Note however that the first argument in all instances of `MYARR` must be the explicit constant `1` or `2`, not a more complex expression with this value.

Comment: Incredibly easy solution. I guess I couldn't quite figure it out.  Thanks!